# Capitalize First Letter of the month in Datetimepicker language: nl(netherlands) not with css

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

Any solution except for the **style/css** solution.
I try to use the .change() but when i clicked outside the inputbox it will return to the current date. the text-transform: capitalize solution is not preferable for me because in the email sent, it will return to lowercase. Also, the nl(netherland) language only the problem, other language are fine.

Here's the sample code in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNGLaM)

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('nl');
        $( 'input' ).datetimepicker({
            timepicker:false,
            format:'F d, Y',
            maxDate: '0',
            i18n: {
                nl: {
                    months: [
                        "Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }).keypress(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }).change(function(){
    var value = $('input').val();
    var capitalized = value[0].toUpperCase() + value.substr(1);

    $('input').val(capitalized);
  });
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Month name is capitalized in your code already. Is there something you missed ?

Comment: see it in the codepen. after selecting date, in the input it will display capitalized but when you clicked outside the input it will change to another date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of change use blur event of jQuery

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('nl');
            $( 'input' ).datetimepicker({
                timepicker:false,
                format:'F d, Y',
                maxDate: '0',
                i18n: {
                    nl: {
                        months: [
                            "Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }).keypress(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }).blur(function(){
        var value = $('input').val();
        var capitalized = value[0].toUpperCase() + value.substr(1);

        $('input').val(capitalized);
      }).change(function(){
    $(':focus').blur();
  });
```

Here is the working Sample : [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbXdrY)

Comment: thanks. it work, but it is possible to make it on right away after selecting date? it will only trigger when i click outside the input

Comment: Try below code, basically when the input value is changed it will trigger the blur event, which will give you the desired effect.